# how to add or connect two project like a one project in xCode 4 or higher

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.6

i have two different project i want both project or project files add or connect each other or
 in one project and when i run the one project then we excess, send or get values form connecting project if it is possible if yes then help me. Thankes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a workspace.. This allows you to use stuff from any attached project in the workspace.

Comment: i am using workspace but i don't know how to add files or connect

Comment: #import <MyNiceProject/MySuperFile.h> like you are doing with frameworks. You cannot do an application controlling another application on iOS

Comment: you have any link for this

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Workspace.html

Comment: any other help or link